# How to use slam toolbox?

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've seen the introduction of [slam toolbox](https://github.com/SteveMacenski/slam_toolbox), but have no idea what exactly tools it has(launch files or nodes), how to use them, what input do I need to give, and what their output is.

I think this has a great relationship with my lack of understanding of SLAM

But I still want to ask if there is a more detailed document so that I can use the slam toolbox with the only understanding of the input and output

Thanks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/377606/how-to-use-slam-toolbox?/) by [JonyK](https://answers.ros.org/users/72345/jonyk/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2021-05-04

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Immanuel](https://answers.ros.org/users/78407/immanuel/) on 2021-07-22**:
I kind of agree. The documentation is pretty less and there is very little information about the launch files, how to run them etc (example: what is to be used when we have a rosbag and want to create a map later, when does one use the online sync launch, the online async launch, etc). I am using the melodic branch of the slam_toolbox. The ROSCON talk and the readme give some amount of information but it is not very clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My recommendation would be to look at the [Nav2_Bringup SLAM example](https://navigation.ros.org/tutorials/docs/navigation2_with_slam.html) which demonstrates the basic use of the slam_toolbox on a turtlebot3 robot, and includes typical configuration values.

The github link you included also contains quite a bit of the information you are looking for, if you scroll down to the API section. Consider the `inputs` to be the Subscribed Topics and the Configuration Parameters.

---

Originally posted by [shonigmann](https://answers.ros.org/users/69938/shonigmann/) with karma: 1567 on 2021-05-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [JonyK](https://answers.ros.org/users/72345/jonyk/) on 2021-05-05**:
Thanks a lot. But I have no physical turtlebot3 robot. Can this run with a simulated robot?

**Comment by [shonigmann](https://answers.ros.org/users/69938/shonigmann/) on 2021-05-05**:
Yes, if you look at the [nav2_bringup package](https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation2/blob/main/nav2_bringup/bringup/README.md) on github you'll get a bit more information on running navigation2 in simulation.

if memory serves, it will be something to the effect of:

`ros2 launch nav2_bringup tb3_simulation_launch.py slam:=True`